# Can Paypal allow unlimited withdraws with a single user agreement

Tags: paypal

I have a merchant site.
I wonder if the following scenario is possible :
A customer subscribes a "full shop access" and I can withdraw money from it's paypal account when he purcahses something. He does not have to login to paypal or anything at anytime but the moment he chose "full shop access".
Given that money amount will be differents.

I found a lot of thing about recurrent payment but it's on given periods and given amounts therefore it's not at all what I need.

I just want the customer to say paypal once : "OK, I trust this website, it can get my money anytime he needs to".

So if it's possible, can anyone give me a link to documention about this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [Create a token](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) using `SetExpressCheckout` with the `L_BILLINGTYPE0` set to `MerchantInitiatedBilling`

2) [Create a billing agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateBillingAgreement_API_Operation_NVP/) using `CreateBillingAgreement` and pass `TOKEN` for the response after redirecting the user to PayPal.

3) [Charge their billing agreement id](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) using `DoReferenceTransaction`.

This method requires you to get approval from PayPal to use Reference Transactions.

Comment: Thaks you very much !